# Why does a clojure future block the main thread?

Tags: clojure

I have a trivial lein project where `-main` contains a future:

```
(def f (future 42))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println @f))
```

When I run `lein run` it prints `42` but does not return.

I don't understand why it does not return ?

How do I get `lein run` to return ?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not return"? Do you mean that `lein` hangs forever?

Answer (score 8):

Your question is really twofold:

1. Why does lein not return?

lein hangs because the thread pool which backs Clojure futures does not use daemon threads so you have to explicitly shut it down. If you change your code to the following, it should work:

```
(def f (future 42))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println @f)
  (shutdown-agents))
```

2. Futures block the main thread

The line `(println @f)` can potentially block the main thread when "derefing" `f` if the future hasn't finished its job yet.

This is a limitation of Clojure futures that can be addressed using [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async) or [RxClojure](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxClojure). I've also been working on an alternative implementation of futures for Clojure that I plan to open source very soon and addresses these issues.

Comment: Why not just check the return value of `(realized? f)` before you deref? `(if (realized? f) @f "pending...")`

Comment: That is not enough. If it's not realized yet, you'll need a way to wait and keep trying which will tie up another thread (or the main thread). What you really want is the ability to run a piece of code once a future completes. That doesn't exist yet. And starting another thread just to wait for a future is overkill.