# How to perform synchronous parallel functions in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, parallel-processing

I have an application which has an initial flow that can be done in parallel:

1. **Fetch two JSON documents** (I use [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http) for that)
2. **Parse these documents** (extract only required data)
3. Join the results
4. Dump them into a one file

So there's something like that:

```
some-entry-point
      /\
     /  \
    /    \
   /      \
fetchA   fetchB
  |         |
  |         |
parseA   parseB
  \        /
   \      /
    \    /
     \  /
      \/
     join
      |
      |
     dump
```

What is the correct and the most current way to achieve that?

What I found so far are:

- [promises](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/promise)
- [futures](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/future)
- [delay](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/delay)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have exactly two branches here, it'll be best to dispatch parallel jobs to separate threads using [future](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/future) function. [future](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/future) will return you a future object (a special promise which will be automatically resolved when the job will be completed).

Here is how it will look:

```
(defn some-entry-point
  [obja objb]
  (let [pa (-> (fetchA obja)
               parseA
               future)
        pb (-> (fetchB objb)
               parseB
               future)]
    (-> (join @pa @pb)
        dump)))
```

`@` here is a shortcut (reader macro) for [deref](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deref) function.

Or course, you could execute one of you branches in main thread, creating only one future object:

```
(defn some-entry-point
  [obja objb]
  (let [p (-> (fetchB objb)
              parseB
              future)]
    (-> (fetchA obja)
        parseA
        (join @p)
        dump)))
```

You could also generalize this approach to fetch and parse multiple objects using some general `fetch` and `parse` functions, using [pmap](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/pmap) for paralelization:

```
(defn some-entry-point
  "Fetch and parse multiple objects in parallel"
  [objs]
  (->>  objs
        (pmap (comp parse fetch))
        (apply join)
        dump))
```

Comment: Alright, it seems to be working, but why do I need to `(shutdown-agents)` to let my program exit immediately? I have an issue described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014241/why-does-a-clojure-future-block-the-main-thread

Comment: @squixy just checked it on my `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS` with `Clojure 1.6.0` and `Leiningen 2.5.1 on Java 1.8.0_45 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM` and everything worked fine without `(shutdown-agents)`. It looks like some platform/JVM specific problem. Try updating your JVM. If it won't help, then you'll have to call `(shutdown-agents)` explicitly, though it doesn't look like a big problem to me.

Comment: `lein -v => Leiningen 2.5.1 on Java 1.8.0_40 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
` so idk why is that.

Comment: A correction: `future` does not return a promise, it returns a future. See also the `future?` predicate.

Comment: I thought they had changed this, but Clojure agents use non-daemon threads (here: http://clojure.org/agents search for 'daemon'). The JVM will not shut down if there are non-daemon threads running.

Comment: @Bill there is [an issue about it](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-124), though, for some reason, not all systems are affected. My JVM shuts down all right.